# Advance search in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2016, enterprise-search, advanced-search

Where can I find advance search webpart/page in Sharepoint 2016.

Comment: Did you configure your Search services and enterprise search site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please check whether search service application is set up. You can create enterprise search site from site templates when creating site. Then when you search you will get advanced search pages

**Edit 1**

there are 2 ways you can do this.First is use same page which Microsoft is using which is as follows

1)advanced search page layout is in the following folder which you have to upload in masterpage gallery

\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PortalLayouts

After that create advancedsearch.aspx in sitepages and add the advanced search webpart in that

```
<File Url="advanced.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/advancedsearchlayout.aspx, Advcanced search page layout" />
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Advanced search" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="MainZone" WebPartOrder="1">
        <![CDATA[
                    <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
                        <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                        <TypeName>Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox</TypeName>
                        <Title>$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,AdvancedSearch_Webpart_Title;</Title>
                        <Description>$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,AdvancedSearch_Webpart_Description;</Description>
                        <FrameType>None</FrameType>
                        <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
                        <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
                        <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
                        <SearchResultPageURL xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">results.aspx</SearchResultPageURL>
                        <ShowAndQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowAndQueryTextBox>
                        <ShowPhraseQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowPhraseQueryTextBox>
                        <ShowOrQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowOrQueryTextBox>
                        <ShowNotQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowNotQueryTextBox>
                        <ShowLanguageOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowLanguageOptions>
                        <ShowResultTypePicker xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowResultTypePicker>
                        <ShowPropertiesSection xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowPropertiesSection>
                    </WebPart>
                ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
```

Create this page in sitepages and it will redirect you there.

2)Second Option In the search result webpart you can set the advanced search page url .Set it to any url and it will redirect you there.Create any page in sitepages and add the advanced search webpart in that page after that set the URL

Comment: Thanks John for the reply, in fact could you please help me on how to set up search service application.

Comment: @Santhosh If you used the Farm Configuration Wizard after you installed SharePoint Server 2016, a Search service application might have been created at that time. To verify whether a Search service application exists, you can click Manage service applications in the Application Management section on the Central Administration home page. Check this one and let me know .

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Yes, in central administration Search service application exists and the status is running. Being said that, I cant still identify the Advanced.aspx page nor advancesearch webpart. Kindly guide.

Comment: okay, did you create Enterprise Search site or Basic Search Site? or how your search site was created? Which site Template did you choose?

Comment: When you click on advanced, what's the error message you are getting on enterprise search center

Comment: Thanks again.. Are you referring to /Pages/advanced.aspx if so it says "The page you're looking for doesn't exist."

Comment: Updated Answer , please check it and let me know if that works for you

Comment: Thanks John. In fact it was my bad - wherein the site under discussion was migrated from 2010 environment and was not showing AdvanceSearch webpart in 2016. I then tried creating a new sub site as an Enterprise Search and could identify the newly created sub site does have the advance search feature. Still I am investigating on why the migrated site doesn't have that feature, if you have any clues please do guide. Thanks a lot for your kind gesture in finding time to answer my queries. God bless

Comment: okay, it would have been better if you could have provided all these details. Please upvote or accept answers if that really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Here the is a link that explain how to creat and found advance search :

https://searchexplained.com/configuring-advanced-search-in-sharepoint-2013-and-2016/

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt resolves my requirement. In the post they are mentioning about one page named /Pages/advanced.aspx but i can't find the same in SP 2016 nor a webpart for advance search.  :(

Comment: Did you create enterprise search site or basic search site?

Comment: I think you must activate the right feature to get acces to this page. is the search feature activate???

Comment: @Conyel: Could you please help me on how to activate the search feature in 2016.